# Cannot install -r requirements.txt ... these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 29), -r requirements.txt (line 47) and httpcore>=0.15.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested httpcore==0.18.0
    dnspython 2.4.0 depends on httpcore>=0.17.3; python_version >= "3.8"
    httpx 0.23.0 depends on httpcore<0.16.0 and >=0.15.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

what should i do?

I have tried changing httpcore>=0.15.0 | httpcore>=0.17.3 | httpcore==0.17.3 | httpcore>=0.18.0
but i still get the same error

Comment: Do you specifically need `dnspython==2.4.0` and `httpx==0.23.0`?  Both of those have newer versions available.